# What does "cue the Democratic finger-pointing" mean in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

The following sentence is quoted from a transcript of [NBC NEWS](https://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/meet-press-11-08-20-n1247045). The host said:

> In spite of Joe Biden's win, Democrats are asking themselves some hard questions after an otherwise disappointing election night down the ballot. So far in the Senate, the Senate Democrats have netted only one seat, with Senate control to be decided by two January runoff elections in Georgia. I have to tell you, folks, the amount of money and effort that's going to be thrown into that is something else. Republicans actually gained seats in the House, by the way. **So cue the Democratic finger-pointing.** We've already heard and seen some. Progressives and moderates blaming each other for the results. So joining me now is ...

What does "cue the Democratic finger-pointing" mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[American Heritage Dictionar "cue 2"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cue)

> noun 1. A signal, such as a word or action, used to prompt another event in a performance, such as an actor's speech or entrance, a change in lighting, or a sound effect.
> verb 2. To insert into the sequence of a performance: *cued the lights for the monologue scene.*

[American Heritage Dictionary "finger-pointing"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=finger-pointing)

> The act of blaming someone for something; the imputation of blame.

Putting together the two definitions, the sentence "cue the Democratic finger-pointing" imitates an instruction in a play or screenplay, and it means "Let the assignment of blame begin."